# How to have the inherited properties of superclass appear in an object in the subclass?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, inheritance, dto

I have a DTO that extends an abstract base DTO with a message property and the getters and setters. Currently, when I run my service I get this JSON object as the output.

```
{
    "message": null,
    "id_key": "014",
    "status_flag": null,
    "modified_by": "Dev",
    "modified_date": "2018-05-30"
}
```

The message field is being inherited. Is there a way to set the inherited field to be in its own subobject like this.

```
{
    "_errors": {
        "message": null
    },
    "id_key": "014",
    "status_flag": null,
    "modified_by": "Dev",
    "modified_date": "2018-05-30"
}
```

I want to avoid creating a BaseDTO object and the getters and setters in the inheriting class. I am trying to refactor a lot of DTOs and can do a replace all to add extends BaseDTO to every one of them. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code blocks as code blocks (i.e. indent by four whitespaces).

Comment: don't have message in the base class, and put errors and message in the subclass

Comment: Im trying to avoid doing that to make implementation easier. Not every DTO will use this. Do you know if there is a way to map the class object to my own custom JSON structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an "Errors" class:

```
public class Errors {

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;

    ...
}
```

and use it in you BaseDTO:

```
@JsonProperty("_errors")
public Errors errors;
```

So, every class that inherit BaseDTO will have the "_errors" property with "message" property inside.

Comment: I ended up doing this but I have a class inherit my base. Your way works better though as I need a special method to be able to instantiate the object since its abstract. Thanks! This really helps!